# Array validation on a field at collection creation on Mongodb using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I've got a little problem using MongoDB 3.2, PHP 5.6.16 with the PHPDriver mongod 1.1 and the 'official' MongoDB PHPLIB

I want to create a collection with a validator:

```
createCollection('client',[
'validator' => [
  'total' => ['$type' => 'int'],
  'Appliref' => ['$type'=> 'array'],
],
]);
```

If I do like presented, Mongo will check on insertion that my document contains 
'total' which is an Int;
And 'Appliref' which contains an array

( ! It will not check if Appliref is an array only if it contains an array:

For example :

```
insertOne([
  'total'=>55,
  'Appliref'=>array('1224','4447')]; will not be ok
insertOne([
  'total'=>55,
  'Appliref'=>array('1224',array('1111','2222'))]; will be ok )
```

The explanation is in the documentation of [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

but my goal is, of course, to validate both, more specifically to check if Appliref is an array or not.

I found a solution on an other Website :

```
db.createCollection("user" , { validator : { "hoge.0" : {$exists : true}}})
```

the idea is to check if the first element of the array exists;

I can't find a way to do it in PHP using the => and I not sure it's the perfect solution

If someone got a solution ( for a PHP use please :( ) or a way to use the solution I found in PHP that would be great,

Sorry for bad English, if there is.

Answer (score 0):

> Create an user define function with two parameters. One is for passing
>   collection name and another one is for passing the array. Now at the
>   definition part of the function you can check the array as following
>   code.

```
function createMyCollection($collectionName,$array){
    if(is_array($array)){
       createCollection($collectionName,$array);
    }else{
       die("Invalid Array");
    }
}
```